# How to make a regex pattern that fits

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to learn regex and came across a question I cannot solve. The pattern looks like this:

> **A1234567 4**DFDGB
>
> **B1234567 1234**DFDRR
>
> **C1234567 12**DBFDG

The parts I want are the highlited ones. 1 letter followed by 7 numbers then a space and less than 5 numbers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this one: `[A-Z]\d{7}\s\d{0,5}`

Comment: @Botond instead of waiting for someone to hopefully provide you the correct answer can you kindly show us what you have tried and or attempted on your own..? also please show an example of what your expected output should look like to.. this is not a `Code Provider Service Site BTW`

Comment: I use following reference guide for regex : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the link! I will use it from now on.

Comment: @MethodMan I'm sorry for the wrong use of the site. I've tried on my own and struggled to find a simple guide that i can understand. The offical website of Microsoft is too dry for me. I'm already pleased with simple links I got in the answes where I can practice. Sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: For learning regex I recommend https://regexone.com/. Im not affiliated or anything. Its just 15 little exercice about regex with correction. With a nice progression. you won't b expert but you will have enought understanding to be better.

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks for the link! I've checked it out and it's really useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then this is what you need

```
[A-Z]{1}\d{7}\s\d{1,5}
```

View details:

- `[A-Z]{1}` - 1 letter from the A-Z range
- `\d{7}` - 7 digits
- `\s` - space
- `\d{1,5}` - numbers range from 1 to 5

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w{1}([\d ]+))
```

This Will Work

> `\w{1}` - Will match 1 Letter
>
> `([\d ]+))` - Will match any digits and spaces 
>   or `([\d ]{1,6})` Which will only match up to 5

[Example here](http://regexr.com/3s7p4)

Comment: *Counter example*: `C1234567 1 2 3` (please, notice **3** spaces)

Comment: Since `\w` matches *digit* `1234567` is another *counter example*